# Sending an email using MailGun on AppHarbor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, appharbor, mailgun

I'm trying to send a simple email to my users using AppHarbor and the MailGun addon. I also installed the MailGun NuGet package to send email easier from my C# code.

I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Domain not found
```

Here is the code I'm running:

```
/* Send welcome email. */
var client = new MailgunClient("foo.apphb.com", "key-1-jpn-190fj8102i3nf12i3fno213f");
client.SendMail(new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("welcome@foo.apphb.com", "sergiotapia@outlook.com")
{
    Subject = "Hello from mailgun",
    Body = "this is a test message from mailgun."
});
```

Any ideas why this error message is popping up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably shouldn't use `foo.apphb.com` when configuring the MailGun client. I'm guessing, but you should probably use the `MAILGUN_SMTP_SERVER` configuration variable that's injected when your app is deployed on AppHarbor.

Answer (score 2):

MailGun provides a Domain Name when you integrate with you application. Use this domain name here. It should be something similar to "abcd.mailgun.org".

Answer (score 0):

`ping foo.apphb.com`, I for one get no response.